# How can I define a paramter in a function.

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make the function dice randomly roll from 1-6. But when I try to add the different numbers from the function, it says that one and two are undefined. I'm not sure to how solve this, and I'm pretty new at coding.

```
import random
    def dice(name):
        name = random.randint(1,6)
        print name
    dice('one')
    dice('two')
    dicesum = float(one) + float(two)
    message = raw_input('guess the number. ')
    if dicesum == message:
        print "You guess right! You win!"
    if dicesum != message:
        print "You guess wrong! You lose!"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `one` and `two` to represent the values returned by the dice roll:

```
import random


def roll_dice():
    value = random.randint(1, 6)
    print(value)
    return value


roll_one = roll_dice()
roll_two = roll_dice()
dice_sum = roll_one + roll_two
guess = int(input('guess the number. '))  # cast to int so it can be compared to dice_sum
if dice_sum == guess:
    print("You guess right! You win!")
else:
    print("You guess wrong! You lose!")
```

I changed the variable names and function names to what I think is a better representation of what they are and do.

Comment: Converting the number to a string instead of converting the string to a number seems clumsier. If the user types `09`, and the answer is 9, should they really be told they guessed wrong?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was debating whether I wanted to change it or not - I will, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When you write `name = random.randint(1, 6)`, that doesn't look at the current value of `name` and then create a new variable named whatever that value is; it just reassigns the variable `name`.

And, even if it *did* create a new variable, it would be a local variable, unusable outside the function.

What you really want to do here is not take a parameter at all:

```
def dice():
    return random.randint(1,6)

one = dice()
two = dice()
dicesum = float(one) + float(two)
```

---

As a side note, you really don't need that `float` there. The numbers are already ints, and all you're doing with them is adding them and comparing to a string. You don't want the user to have to guess `7.0` (or, worse, `7.0000000000000000001`), you want them to guess `7`, right? So just use `int`.

Meanwhile, you *do* need to convert the user's input to a number. `raw_input` just returns a string. and the string `'7'` is not equal to the number `7` (whether it's an `int` or a `float`). So:

```
one = dice()
two = dice()
dicesum = one + two
message = int(raw_input('guess the number. '))
```

---

If you actually *did* want to create a new global variable inside the function, that's *possible*. But it's almost always a very bad idea. To create a new global variable dynamically, you have to use the [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function to get the global namespace as a dict, then work on that dict. Like this:

```
def dice(name):
    value = random.randint(1,6)
    globals()[name] = value
```

But, again, this is almost always a very bad idea. Creating global variables from within a function is already a fishy thing to do. And good reasons for creating variables by name dynamically are even rarer. After all, you're not going to access the variable as `globals()['one']`, but as `one`, so you almost certainly want to create the variable not as `globals()['one']`, but as `one`. As in the example at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`dicesum = float(one) + float(two)` should result in an error, since you have no variables called `one, two`. What you do have is `dice('one'),dice('two')`.

If you assign the results into variables `one, two = dice('one'),dice('two')` that would solve that. However, your `dice` function does not return a value, so that needs fixing too.

One last thing, `if dicesum == message:` will never be `True` since `message` is a `str` while `dicesum` is a `float`. Fix by casting `message` to a float

```
import random
def dice(name):
    name = random.randint(1,6)
    print (name)
    return name # return value!

one = dice('one') # assign variables!!
two = dice('two') # assign variables!!
dicesum = float(one) + float(two)
message = float(raw_input('guess the number. ')) # cast!
if dicesum == message:
    print ("You guess right! You win!")
if dicesum != message: # this line can be shortened into "else:"
    print ("You guess wrong! You lose!")
```

Comment: I think you're missing the OP's confusing. He was hoping that `name = …`, when `name` is the string `'one'`, would create a new variable named `one`. It's hard to explain why that's wrong, but that's what needs to be explained here.